# Given a Div with a set height and overflow set to scroll - How to determine if an item is above the fold?

Tags: jquery, html

Is this possible? Given a div of say max-height 400 with overflow set to scroll. If the inner contents have a height of 1000, how can I determine if an item in the inner div is visible or below/above the overflow?

Comment: That, my friend, is an age-old question that every single web developer comes across one day or another. (I think it has a solution though, just can't remember it :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery( ".content" ).each( function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.offsetTop > this.parentNode.offsetHeight ? "below" : "above";
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4E3DH/3/

`position:relative;` (or any non static position) for the container is a must.

Comment: Thanks but that does update on scroll. I want to know based on the scroll position if the item in view viewable or hidden

Comment: @AnApprentice, ah, actually I am using that functionality already in a real app.. let me dig into the code.

Comment: @AnApprentice, is this what you want? (with more accurate calculations) http://jsfiddle.net/4E3DH/4/ Here's more accurate calculations but you can't see if it's working ;) http://jsfiddle.net/4E3DH/5/